# Is the set of all concave functions a convex set?

Tags: convex-analysis

How can I prove this?

I saw a similar question here: (But this was only for when g(x) is ≥0)
[Prove that a set defined by concave functions on $R^n$ is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165618/prove-that-a-set-defined-by-concave-functions-on-rn-is-convex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let 
$$S=\{g\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}\ \text{s.t}\ g\ \text{concave}\}$$
For $a,b\in[0,1]$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $g,f\in S$ we have:
\begin{align} (af+(1-a)g)(bx+(1-b)y)  &=af(bx+(1-b)y)+(1-a)g(bx+(1-b)y)\\
&\geq a(bf(x)+(1-b)f(y))+(1-a)(bg(x)+(1-b)g(y))\\
&=b(af(x)+(1-a)g(x))+(1-b)(af(y)+(1-a)g(y))\\
&=b(af+(1-a)g)(x) +(1-b)(af+(1-a)g))(y).
\end{align}

Then, $af+(1-a)g$  is concave so it belongs $S$ and hence $S$is convex set.

Comment: @AlexParker You're welcome.